# Should we unregister the OnBackPressedCallback?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, onbackpressed

Starting from SDK 33 the `onBackPressed()` method is deprecated and as a replacement, I want to use the `onBackPressedDispatcher` property instead.

To avoid memory leaks, should we somehow unregister the `OnBackPressedCallback` in the `onDestroy` method?

[image: Available options for the OnBackPressedDispatcher object]

Comment: If you provide lifecycleOwner, then you do not need to handle onDestroy() method https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher#addCallback(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback) If you do not provide lifecyleOwner, then you have to unregister manually https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher#addCallback(androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback)

Comment: @Alper Özaslan i think so you are correct